# Only get 1st element of TABLE in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have this code:

```
public LinkedList<Product> getAllProduct(String idtask){
    LinkedList<Product> products = new LinkedList<Product>();
    Cursor localCursor = this.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_PRODUCT+" WHERE "+KEY_ID_PRODUCT_TASK+"='"+idtask+"'", null);
    Product product;
    if (localCursor.moveToFirst())
        do {
            product = new Product();
            product.setKEY_ID_UNIQUE_PRODUCT(localCursor.getString(0));
            product.setKEY_ID_PRODUCT_TASK(localCursor.getString(1));
            product.setKEY_ID_PRODUCT(localCursor.getString(2));
            product.setKEY_NAME_PRODUCT(localCursor.getString(3));
            product.setKEY_QTY_PRODUCT(localCursor.getString(4));
            product.setKEY_SIZE_PRODUCT(localCursor.getString(5));
            products.add(product);
        } while (localCursor.moveToNext());
    return products;
}
```

I only get 1 row, when with a particular IdTasks, I have to get 2 elements. Please Help me, I don't Know whats the problem. Because, when I debugging I add 2 products with this IdTask in the Table product, but when I try to get these products with this IdTask, I only get the first.

Here is the code with I add products int he table PRODUCT

```
public void addProduct(Product product)
{   
        SQLiteDatabase localSQLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues localContentValues = new ContentValues();

        if (!isExistIDProduct(product.getKEY_ID_PRODUCT())){
            localContentValues.put(KEY_ID_PRODUCT_TASK, product.getKEY_ID_PRODUCT_TASK());
            localContentValues.put(KEY_ID_PRODUCT, product.getKEY_ID_PRODUCT());
            localContentValues.put(KEY_NAME_PRODUCT, product.getKEY_NAME_PRODUCT());
            localContentValues.put(KEY_QTY_PRODUCT, product.getKEY_QTY_PRODUCT());
            localContentValues.put(KEY_SIZE_PRODUCT, product.getKEY_SIZE_PRODUCT());
            localSQLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_PRODUCT, null, localContentValues);        
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you check localCursor.getCount() and got 1?

Comment: what about the code that you use to add records? bye

Comment: Yes, that's not the way add records to your list. Use:
while (localCursor.moveToNext()) {
    // add data
}

Comment: But I need the producs with this TASKID

Comment: `addProduct()` only  adds a single row. Show the code that calls `addProduct()` in order to add 2 rows with the same `KEY_ID_PRODUCT_TASK` value. Also, is the following test somehow preventing you from adding the second row?: `if (!isExistIDProduct(product.getKEY_ID_PRODUCT()))`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see whats happening. I have asigned some Taks in the server, to test this. And all of the idProduct are 0, and my table Product I only have 1 product, for the 1st tasks. Thanks man :D

Comment: Glad I was able to help. I have created an answer with the solution so that this question can be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using test data that reuses the same product IDs, then the following test is preventing you from adding the second row:

```
if (!isExistIDProduct(product.getKEY_ID_PRODUCT()))
```

Comment: This `if` checks for product ID not task ID, though.

Comment: Yes, but I suspected the data used was test data, and the product IDs were all the same. And I was right. See the comments to the question.

Comment: I have updated my answer to make this point more clear. Thanks.